# ASP.NET Always include Kerberos authentication in client response

Tags: c#, jquery, security, iis, kerberos

Is there a way to configure IIS or mark up my code so that the client (any major modern browser) will always include Kerberos information in the response without having to make any modifications to the client itself?

In this specific server method, I'm using ASP.NET impersonation with delegation enabled in AD and it would seem that from firefox and a few other clients, Kerberos data is not being passed from the client to the server.

My application only has Windows Authentication enabled, but how can I force the requests to pass Kerberos information along?

If it helps, I'm using jquery's ajax to GET or POST my requests to the server.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your server is returning "WWW-Authenticate" headers that indicate it accepts Kerberos authentication ("Negotiate"), the client should automatically supply the necessary credentials.  Make sure that Negotiate is listed as a possible provider for Windows Authentication in the Authentication configuration of your application.  You'll probably want to disable NTLM in that list.

You can tell if the client is sending Kerberos tickets if you look at the HTTP headers.  It should have something like "Authorization: Negotiate YIIN..."; the first few base64 characters of the payload let you distinguish between Kerberos and NTLM.